# Pandas adding extra column to end of dataframe even though index_col=False and index=False

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a dataset in multiple .csv files from a device in our lab (XRF) that has a standard output format. I created a script to clean up all the data and used one file to create/test and it works great. I then added a loop to add all the different files into one dataframe for the whole dataset. When I read_csv the files in, the first file is fine, 299 columns. But the next files all have an added column at the end called 'Unnamed: 299'.

```
#Name of directory
fdir = 'F:/Grad School/Research/Pearl_River/Data_Collection/XRF_Data/ForScript'

#Get files from file directory (fdir)
all_files = Path(fdir).glob('*.csv')

#Empty list for data
dfs = []

#Loop through files
for file in all_files:
    data = pd.read_csv(file, index_col=False)
    dfs.append(data)

#Read into a dataframe from list (this is best practice and faster)
df = pd.concat(dfs)
```

[image]

I have tried changing index_col=None, no difference. I tried changing index_col=0 and all the files had one less column but the two files at the end *still* had an 'Unnamed' column added to the end of them.

I opened all three files and they are all identical as far as columns are concerned. Within Excel they all end at column KM. This is expected as the device has a standard format for output that is always identical.

Right now I only have three files but in the future there could be any number of files so it is not feasible to always manually check the files though it doesn't seem to be an issue with the raw files anyway.

Comment: Could it be that some column in between is duplicated in the other files?

Comment: @rr_goyal I've compared them and there are not any duplicated columns. I might try resaving the data from the device and see if that's any different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is expected that there will be an extra comma at the end of your CSV file.

csv file example

```
col1,col2,    <-- extra comma after col2
a1,a2
b1,b2
```

make csv file to data frame

```
import io
import pandas as pd
text = '''col1,col2,
a1,a2
b1,b2'''
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(text))
```

`df`

```
    col1    col2    Unnamed: 2
0   a1      a2      NaN
1   b1      b2      NaN
```

Unnamed : 2 (integer locaion) is created

There is something wrong with the data at the 300th position in one or more of the files.

---

However, it does not seem to be a big problem because the Unnamed column can be simply deleted.

```
df.loc[:, ~df.columns.str.startswith('Unnamed')]
```

output:

```
    col1    col2
0   a1      a2
1   b1      b2
```

Comment: They all have the extra comma at the end but only the last two have the extra column. I have other columns I remove later using .startswith or .contains so I can definitely do it that way. Was hoping I could fix it while reading it in.

Comment: Update, I was able to delete the extra columns. I redownloaded the data as well and the issue was not in the new download so it might have gotten corrupted somehow.